# Do I need to run compaction on each node of the cluster in cassandra 3

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

We are having 4 node cassandra cluster . Do I need to run compact and repair on each node of the cluster ?

Cassandra Version:- Cassandra 3.0.10
No of nodes in a cluster : 4
Replication Factor :- 4
Compaction Strategy:- LeveledCompactionStrategy

Thanks

Comment: Just curious, but why a RF of 4?  That means only one node can go down before you start seeing issues querying at QUORUM.

Comment: We have distribution of 4 nodes in 2 data centers. 2 nodes in 1 datacenter and 2 nodes in another. Also the data size is small so we have RF as 4

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question, "Yes" compaction needs to run on all nodes.

The *right* answer, is that **you** shouldn't be the one running compaction.  Cassandra is almost always capable of figuring out when to run compaction on its own, and you **should not need to invoke it manually.**

In fact, once you run compaction manually, the odds of compaction happening organically in the future are minuscule, so then you're stuck having to do it manually.

Similar answer on DBA.StackExchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71781/cassandra-maintenance/74213#74213

Answer (score 1):

Yep, compaction is done automatically, but you should run a regular **repair**